# How do I access a particular child and its text using event.target?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Consider this **HTML** code:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="c1">Text1
<p class="pc1">Paragraph1</p>
</div>
<div class="c1">Text2
<p class="pc1">Paragraph2</p>
</div>
</div>
```

And here's **Script** I'm trying:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#container").click(function(e){
var a=e.target.children().text();
//I want to store the text in the paragraph (e.g. Paragraph 1, when I click the first div) in var a.
var b=e.target.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
//I want to store the text in the div (e.g. Text1, when I click the first div) in var b.
});
});
</script>
```

But it's not working. I know I've written something wrong. What is the correct way to access those texts using **event.target** property?

Comment: Please make a better effort to format your code properly. Using consistent and proper indentations makes your code much more readable.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `e.target` is it could be either the `c1` element or the `pc1` element.

You can target the `c1` element with the click event and then find the first child of the `c1` and its value

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#container").on('click', '.c1', function(e) {
    var text = this.firstChild.nodeValue.trim();
    snippet.log(text);
  });
  //using a gloabl handler, they way you have used
  $("#container").click(function(e) {
    var text = $(e.target).closest('div').contents().first().text();
    snippet.log('2: ' + text);
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="c1">Text1
    <p class="pc1">Paragraph1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c1">Text2
    <p class="pc1">Paragraph2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#container").click(function(e) {
    var a = $(e.target).children().text();
    //I want to store the text in the paragraph (e.g. Paragraph 1, when I click the first div) in var a.
    alert(a)
    //I want to store the text in the div (e.g. Text1, when I click the first div) in var b.
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="c1">Text1
    <p class="pc1">Paragraph1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c1">Text2
    <p class="pc1">Paragraph2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add `$()` to make it jquery object then you can use `.children()`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are after the `e.target`'s `text node` as well as the `nested <p>`, using jQuery `.contents()` filter would be a better option.

```
  $("#container").children().click(function(e) {        // limit events to children of #container
    var selectElm = $(e.target);
    var a,b;  
    selectElm.contents().filter( function(index,node){  // filter through the contents of selected elm 
      if(index === 0 ){                                 // only takes values of the first node (text only)
        selectElm.is('p') ? a = $(this).text() : b = $(this).text() ; // assign a and b vars
      }    
    });
  });
```

See [Demo](http://codepen.io/CreativeCreate/pen/WwzWmL?editors=1011)

...and the shorter version w/o using `.contents()`,

```
$("#container").children().click(function(e) {        // limit events to children of #container
    var a,b;  
    $(e.target).is('p') ? a = e.target.childNodes[0].nodeValue : b =    e.target.childNodes[0].nodeValue ;
});
```